# Symfony - Getting a Supported Languages List

Tags: symfony, internationalization

I've been searching around, but I've yet to find a built-in way to get a list of language your particular symfony app supports (i.e., a list of languages that have translation files in the project).  Pretty much every code sample I've seen has just hardcoded an array of supported languages, but I'd much prefer a dynamic solution.  The only other way I can think of is to actually just look at the names of the messages.language.yml files, but I wanted to verify first that there isn't some built in way of doing this?

Comment: You pretty much answered your question. Going threw the folder is one option. The other one (which I would personally opt for) is to add a parameter called supported_locales: [ 'fr', 'en', 'ru' ] in parameters.yml. It's not like you're going to add a new locale everyday and it takes less then a minute to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way.

The only way to discover all languages for which you have translation files is to look for all folders containing translations and grab the locales from files.